# Can't do fstream >> int *?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, pointers, file-io, fstream

In the stdio, omething like:

```
int *x = 435345435;
FILE* file = fopen("file", "r");
fscanf(file, "%d", x);
```

works fine, but with streams:

```
int *x = 43532;
fstream file("file");
file >> x;
```

Gives me some crazy ass compiler error:

```
error C2678: binary '>>' : no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'std::fstream' (or there is no acceptable conversion)
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\istream(1053): could be 'std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::operator >><std::char_traits<char>>(std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits> &&,signed char *)' [found using argument-dependent lookup]
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\istream(1060): or       'std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::operator >><std::char_traits<char>>(std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits> &&,signed char &)' [found using argument-dependent lookup]
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\istream(1067): or       'std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::operator >><std::char_traits<char>>(std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits> &&,unsigned char *)' [found using argument-dependent lookup]
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\istream(1074): or       'std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::operator >><std::char_traits<char>>(std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits> &&,unsigned char &)' [found using argument-dependent lookup]
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\istream(1097): or       'std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::operator >><std::char_traits<char>>(std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits> &,signed char *)' [found using argument-dependent lookup]
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\istream(1104): or       'std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::operator >><std::char_traits<char>>(std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits> &,signed char &)' [found using argument-dependent lookup]
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\istream(1111): or       'std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::operator >><std::char_traits<char>>(std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits> &,unsigned char *)' [found using argument-dependent lookup]
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\istream(1118): or       'std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::operator >><std::char_traits<char>>(std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits> &,unsigned char &)' [found using argument-dependent lookup]
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\istream(1128): or       'std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::operator >><char,std::char_traits<char>,int*>(std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits> &&,_Ty &)' [found using argument-dependent lookup]
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>,
1>              _Ty=int *
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\istream(179): or       'std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits>::operator >>(std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits> &(__cdecl *)(std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits> &))'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\istream(185): or       'std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits>::operator >>(std::basic_ios<_Elem,_Traits> &(__cdecl *)(std::basic_ios<_Elem,_Traits> &))'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\istream(192): or       'std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits>::operator >>(std::ios_base &(__cdecl *)(std::ios_base &))'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\istream(199): or       'std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits>::operator >>(std::_Bool &)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\istream(218): or       'std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits>::operator >>(short &)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\istream(253): or       'std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits>::operator >>(unsigned short &)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\istream(272): or       'std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits>::operator >>(int &)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\istream(298): or       'std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits>::operator >>(unsigned int &)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\istream(316): or       'std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits>::operator >>(long &)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\istream(334): or       'std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits>::operator >>(unsigned long &)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\istream(354): or       'std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits>::operator >>(__int64 &)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\istream(373): or       'std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits>::operator >>(unsigned __int64 &)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\istream(392): or       'std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits>::operator >>(float &)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\istream(411): or       'std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits>::operator >>(double &)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\istream(429): or       'std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits>::operator >>(long double &)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\istream(447): or       'std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits>::operator >>(void *&)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\istream(466): or       'std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits>::operator >>(std::basic_streambuf<_Elem,_Traits> *)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>
1>          ]
1>          while trying to match the argument list '(std::fstream, int *)'
```

I'm assuming this is the c++ equivalent of doing this, but it won't work.  How can I go aboot doing this?

Comment: How do you define "works fine"? How do you know that 435345435 converted to a pointer is a valid address to store and integer at and why does the magic pointer value differ in your second example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int *x = 43532;
fstream file("file");
file >> x;
```

What you are telling the compiler to do here is to **read a pointer from a file** (which doesn't make a lot of sense). Your `fscanf` sample does a different thing: It reads an **integer** from the file. With streams, you can write this as such:

```
int *x = 43532;
fstream file("file");
file >> *x;
```

By the way, the error message

```
binary '>>' : no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'std::fstream' 
...
while trying to match the argument list '(std::fstream, int *)'
```

Is trying to tell you that you **cannot** read a pointer in the way your code suggests, because the `>>` operator is not defined for the right-hand type `int*`.

Comment: I see.. so in fscanf, the %d is telling it what to get, and the other argument is telling it where to put it, but with streams it decides what to get and where to put it from the same.. the same thing?  >> x is telling it what to get and where to put it?

Comment: Jcrack: Absolutely. The type of `x` determines how the input is to be interpreted, then the value of `x` is overwritten with that interpretation of the input.

Comment: ok, I think I get it.  So if I wanted to do:

    int x; 
    fscanf(file, "%d", &x);

How would I do that?  I have an idea but I'm not sure what's really going on.

Comment: @Jcrack: That is the simpler, more usual case. You want to read an integer into a variable of type int, so you can just do `int x; stream >> x`. The `>>` operator gets a reference to the right-hand operand, so it can actually modify it.

Comment: @ niklas ok, I get it.  Streams are just automatic like that?  That's what I had assumed but wasn't really sure.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: @Jcrack: C++'s template system makes that possible. You can provide different function implementations for different argument types.

Answer (score 0):

If you make a pointer, you need to use * to get the value.

x is an pointer here, so you need to use *x.